# WPF Check mark missing in checkable MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to use checkable menuitem. But checkmark is not working.
Here is the code

```
<MenuItem Header="Switch to...">
   <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Stroke-Based" StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
   <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Color-Transfer" StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
</MenuItem>
```

[image]

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like there is problem with your template

Comment: Yeah! maybe with MahApps(third party source) but It is working fine in other projects.

Comment: I've checked MahApps [MenuItem template](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/VS/Menu.xaml) and it seems it completely ignores `IsChecked` state. There is no trigger as there is in [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dkozl : Yes! seems like they have completely ignored ischecked trigger. I am trying to add trigger, will let you know after that!

Comment: @SaadAbdullah It would be great if you could post HOW you fixed this for others!

Comment: @dkozl: as suggested, i implemented the IsChecked state property and compiled the code to generate dll. Now, everything's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with Mahapps custom menuitem. Here is the code I added for handling the IsChecked trigger to the existing menuitem xaml-

Add this this "CheckMarkPanel" grid and remove the icon grid. Alternatively you can leave both, but I removed mine.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0"
      Margin="6,0,6,0"
      x:Name="CheckMarkPanel"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Path x:Name="CheckMarkPath"
        Width="7" Height="7"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
        Stroke="#cccccc"
        Fill="Green"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
</Grid>
```

Add these multi trigger conditions -

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                   Value="true" />
        <Condition Property="Role"
                   Value="SubmenuItem" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="CheckMarkPath"
            Property="Visibility"
            Value="Visible" />
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsCheckable"
                   Value="true" />
        <Condition Property="Role"
                   Value="SubmenuItem" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="CheckMarkPanel"
            Property="Visibility"
            Value="Visible" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

And collapse all CheckMarkPanel's visibility for TopLevelHeader/TopLevelItem/subMenutItem.